# sort a dictionary by value and then by keys

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary like this:

```
genre_dict = dict()
genre_dict = {'Action':Action, 'Adventure':Adventure, 'Comedy':Comedy, 'History':History, 'Horror':Horror, 'Romance':Romance}
genre_dict = OrderedDict(genre_dict)
```

I want to sort it decreasingly first by values and if the values were same sort it decreasingly by keys (name of genre).
For example:

```
Action : 3
Comedy : 2
History : 2
Horror : 2
Romance : 2
Adventure : 1
```

I did it by lambda condition but it didn't work for me(its better to say I couldn't).

Comment: "If the keys were the same". Nope, can't be done, in a dict you can't have two keys with the same value. Please start by building some valid input!

Comment: @Óscar Seems like Amin just got the words mixed up. wim just edited and fixed it.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] so we can test possible solutions more easily.

Comment: the content of that dict() doesnt seems to be correct. can you check?

Comment: Is the second mapping your weights for the genres or your desired output? What problem did you encounter using a "lambda condition"?

Comment: BTW you could compress your code down to one line: `genres = OrderedDict({'Action': Action, 'Adventure': Adventure, 'Comedy': Comedy, 'History': History, 'Horror': Horror, 'Romance': Romance})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in one step using the right [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```
OrderedDict(sorted(genre_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])))

OrderedDict([('Action', 3),
             ('Comedy', 2),
             ('History', 2),
             ('Horror', 2),
             ('Romance', 2),
             ('Adventure', 1)])
```

---

Essentially the sorting is taking place based on:

```
[(-x[1],x[0]) for x in genre_dict.items()]

[(-3, 'Action'),
 (-1, 'Adventure'),
 (-2, 'Comedy'),
 (-2, 'History'),
 (-2, 'Horror'),
 (-2, 'Romance')]
```

This little trick enables the sorting for both values in the `tuple` to be done in an `ascending` manner, which is the default ordering criteria. Otherwise we would have to first implement a descending sorting for the second field, and then an ascending one for the first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
genre_dict = dict()
genre_dict = {'Action':3, 'Adventure':1, 'Comedy':2, 'History':2, 'Horror':2, 'Romance':2}
new_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(sorted([(k,genre_dict[k]) for k in genre_dict]), key=lambda x: -x[1]))
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: yatu solution is simpler, use that :) !

Answer (score 0):

By definition, dictionaries are (key,value) pairs, where each key has a unique value pair. So, the input is invalid. If the input is valid, the program works as expected.

Comment: Seems like Amin just got the words mixed up. wim just edited and fixed it.